# C array, why does each element contain the same value?

Tags: arrays, c, gdb

Below is an MRE and the OUTPUT (truncated). When I use gdb, I confirm that each element of my deck array contains each individual card. However, when I iterate through the deck array, all the cards are the Ace of Spades. Why? I've attempted due diligence. The program compiles and runs. The logic seems correct.

COMPILE

```
gcc -g prog33.c -o prog33.exe -Wall
```

MRE

```
//includes
#include <stdio.h>
#define DECK 52

//variable and function declarations
enum suit { clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades }; 
enum value { two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace };
char *Suit[] = {"Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades" };
char *Values[] = {"Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King","Ace" };
char  *deck[DECK];
char mycard[20];

//main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("prog33.c, enums\n");

    for(int s = clubs; s <= spades; s++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n", s, Suit[s]);
        for(int v = two; v <= ace; v++)
        {
            int idx = (s*13) + v;
            sprintf(mycard, "%s of %s", Values[v], Suit[s]);
            printf("    %d, %s, %d, --- %s\n", v, Values[v], idx, mycard);
            deck[idx] = mycard;
            printf("        %i. %s\n", idx, deck[idx]);
        }
    }; 

    for(int i = 0; i < DECK; i++) printf("%d. %s\n", i, deck[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT (truncated)

```
    ...
    11, King, 24, --- King of Diamonds
        24. King of Diamonds
    12, Ace, 25, --- Ace of Diamonds
        25. Ace of Diamonds
2. Hearts
    0, Two, 26, --- Two of Hearts
        26. Two of Hearts
    1, Three, 27, --- Three of Hearts
        27. Three of Hearts
    2, Four, 28, --- Four of Hearts
        28. Four of Hearts
    3, Five, 29, --- Five of Hearts
        29. Five of Hearts
    4, Six, 30, --- Six of Hearts
        30. Six of Hearts
...
    21. Ace of Spades
    22. Ace of Spades
    23. Ace of Spades
    24. Ace of Spades
    25. Ace of Spades
    26. Ace of Spades
    27. Ace of Spades
    28. Ace of Spades
    29. Ace of Spades
    ...
```

Comment: Because you assigned the same thing `mycard` (a pointer converted from the array) to each elements.

Comment: ...and `mycard` contains the *last* string you put there. (Ace and Spades are the last value of the arrays). Try `deck[idx] = strdup(mycard);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it.You will find why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DECK 52

//variable and function declarations
enum suit { clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades }; 
enum value { two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace };
char *Suit[] = {"Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades" };
char *Values[] = {"Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King","Ace" };
char  deck[DECK][128];
char mycard[20];

//main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("prog33.c, enums\n");

    for(int s = clubs; s <= spades; s++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n", s, Suit[s]);
        for(int v = two; v <= ace; v++)
        {
            int idx = (s*13) + v;
            sprintf(mycard, "%s of %s", Values[v], Suit[s]);
            printf("    %d, %s, %d, --- %s\n", v, Values[v], idx, mycard);
            strcpy(deck[idx], mycard);
            printf("        %i. %s\n", idx, deck[idx]);
        }
    }; 

    for(int i = 0; i < DECK; i++) printf("%d. %s\n", i, deck[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or, for a version `malloc`ing (and `free`ing) enough space for `mycard`: https://godbolt.org/z/EP5j5cqKq

Comment: Actually, I liked Weather Vane's suggestion better, but I marked your answer as a solution and upvoted because it gave me a hint. Yeah, I can see the issue, so thank you. and thank you, Weather Vane.

Comment: You could safely change the `128` to a much smaller value — such as 18 (but not smaller than that).  `Queen of Diamonds` needs 18 characters including the null byte.